# Change value in column using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file with five columns. The last column being the students grade level. What I want to do is change the value of that column based on the gradelevel. For example if the gradelevel is 12 I want to change that to 2016, 11 to 2017, so on and so forth.

update: I did get it to semi work using the below:

```
Get-Content users.csv | ForEach-Object -Process {$_ -replace '12','2016'} | Set-Content users1.csv
```

What happens is if the student id has a 12 in it that gets changed as well to 2016. Example would be 120045 gets change to 20160045

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, share an example CSV **and** the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the csv, loop it in a foreach and use the $_ (this) operator and then export ist to csv

Somesthing like:

```
# import CSV
$list = import-csv P:\ath\to\file.csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Standard
# % means foreach
$list | % {
  # The grades is the key for each line
  # the first line of your csv represent the keys you can use
  # e.g. first colum: Name | Grade | Class
  # $_.Name | $_.Grade | $_.Class are your keys for every entry (2nd line and above)

  # here you can work with your grades an do what you want
  if($_.Grade -eq 11){
     # set a new value to the grade in the actual line
     $_.Grade = 2016
  }  
}

# now export the new list into csv
$list | export-csv P:\ath\to\new.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

That should be a basic to work with.

Greetz Eldo.O

Comment: I am getting cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1 
Supply values for the following paremeters:
InputObject:

Answer (score 0):

Eldo you code worked great. I did have to change the last line from:

```
export-csv P:\ath\to\new.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

to

```
$list | Export-Csv P:\ath\to\new.csv -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
```

I was also able to add more if statements to accomplish exactly what I needed.

Comment: oh - I forgot :D - I didn't check the code in runspace, directly codet it into the anwaser :P But nice to see, that it's working for you.